# jQuery/Javascript if width issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, width

I can't seem to get my if statement working. I know that everything inside the if statement works, so would appreciate some help.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(screen.width > 350) {
        $('#search').hide();
        $('.trigger').click(function () {
            $('#search').slideToggle("500");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Place `alert(screen.width);` before `if` statement and tell us what you see.

Comment: Seems to work fine, maybe let us know what you expect vs what's actually happening.

Answer (score 1):

This returns width of browser viewport:

```
$(window).width();
```

This returns width of HTML document:

```
$(document).width();
```

Answer (score 1):

try using:

```
if ($(window).width() > 350) {
```

or

```
 if ($(document).width() > 350) {
```

i hope it helps.

Comment: np, i'm glad it got resolved :) btw, if you like the answer, don't forget to check it off as the answer